# RHEL6: bonding NICs with DHCP reservation problems

Tags: linux, rhel6, bonding, link-layer

I am using a 4 NIC bond with `Bonding Mode: transmit load balancing` and a port channel is configured on the switch.  I have a DHCP reservation for the IP address being used for the bond.  I configured this and restarted network services today, but it's acting really screwy.  I can ping the default gateway, and route shows the correct default gateway, but I cannot ping other IPs on the same subnet.  I can ping google.com by IP, but not by name because I cannot ping/reach any of the DNS servers on my network.  I can randomly communicate with another server on a different subnet, which has allowed me to SSH in.

I am using a Reservation in Infoblox DHCP, should I be using a fixed address instead?  I can ping one of Google's IP addresses, but not another.

**Modprobe.d/bonding.conf:**

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=5 miimon=100
```

**Bond info:**
    Bonding Mode: transmit load balancing
    Primary Slave: None
    Currently Active Slave: eth0
    MII Status: up
    MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
    Up Delay (ms): 0
    Down Delay (ms): 0

```
Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: a0:d3:c1:fd:2d:aa
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: a0:d3:c1:fd:2d:ab
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: a0:d3:c1:fd:2d:ac
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth3
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: a0:d3:c1:fd:2d:ad
Slave queue ID: 0
```

Comment: I don't know if this will fix your problem or not, but using port channel with bonding, LACP / 802.3ad is mode=4, not 5.

Comment: I am afraid it did not resolve the issue, thanks.

Comment: Which mode will obscure the slave MAC addresses and only use the MAC of the bond interface?  Are there any that do that?

Comment: I don't have much experience outside of mode=1 (active / standby) and mode=4 (LACP), so I don't have a definitive answer but my understanding of the various modes.. mode=1 will do that if you explicitly set a different MAC address on the bond.  It's lengthy but the [official docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt) have a lot of detail.  Look under section 15 (Frequently Asked Questions), specifically question 8.